# Meteor - Tracker.nonreactive() is not removing reactivity from helper

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to make a Meteor helper non-reactive with this code:

```
let titleNonReactive;

Template.articleSubmission.onCreated(function () {

    this.autorun(function() {
        titleNonReactive =  Template.currentData().title;
    });

});

Template.articleSubmission.helpers({
    titleNonreactive: function() {
        return titleNonReactive;
    }
});
```

However the resulting output is still reactive. If I save a new value in the background, it's automatically updated on the frontend where I'm displaying the result of this helper with `{{ titleNonreactive }}`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This likely has to do with your Blaze data context; can you show the Blaze template code that refers to both `{{title}}` and `{{titleNonreactive}}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely caused by your Blaze data context (will need to see your Template code to confirm), but here's a possible solution that doesn't involve using `Tracker.nonreactive`. Since you want the value of `titleNonreactive` to not be reactive, you can just use a standard local / non-reactive variable to store a copy of the original reactive title. For example:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { articles } from '/imports/api/articles/collection';
import './main.html';

let originalTitle;

Template.body.onCreated(function onCreated() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    const article = articles.findOne();
    if (article && !originalTitle) {
      originalTitle = article.title;
    }
  });
});

Template.body.helpers({
  article() {
    return articles.findOne();
  },

  titleNonreactive() {
    return originalTitle;
  }
});
```

Then in your Template:

```
<ul>
  {{#with article}}
    <li>Reactive Title: {{title}}</li>
    <li>Non-Reactive Title: {{titleNonreactive}}</li>
  {{/with}}
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm unclear about what syntax you're using at the top of the code there. Meteor doesn't require importing. And you can't just declare a variable in empty space (let originalTitle) as far as I know.

Comment: The data context is the article, so I can just use {{ title }} in the template and it will grab the article title.

Comment: I think this answer is correct. Helpers are always reactive on the data context. When `title` changes, the `Tracker.nonreactive` function is called again, irrespective of any data sources accessed inside of it. Retrieving the data outside of the helper like @hwillson described works around that problem.

Comment: @jetlej I'm using Meteor 1.3+'s ES2015 module support (see the Meteor Guide's [ES2015 modules](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#es2015-modules) section. Using ES2015 modules is recommended for all newer Meteor apps. Regarding declaring a variable outside of Template functions, yes you definitely can. You just have to be careful since anything declared outside of the Blaze Template functions won't necessarily be cleaned up when the Template is removed from the DOM (via [Template#onDestroyed](https://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Template-onDestroyed)).

Comment: @chrisklaussner Exactly!

Comment: @hwillson - Ah that makes sense! This works now that I declared the variable outside of the function. Thank you so much for the detailed answer and explanation!

Comment: I spoke too soon :( I'm using Template.currentData() to set the value for the variable, and it's still reactive. Updating my question with new code now...

Comment: @jetlej Just add a check to see if `titleNonReactive` already has a value set. If it does, don't set it again. This will make sure it gets set the first time, then not again (until the Template is destroyed / re-created). The check I have in my `onCreated` callback does something like this.

Comment: Oh gosh I totally skipped over that. Now it works perfectly. Thanks so much kind stranger :)